# SoundCloud waveform JSON API

Tags: soundcloud

You can get a data representation of the SoundCloud waveform, from this URL:

```
https://wis.sndcdn.com/OVXGhROsaZkq_m.png
```

This feature is undocumented, but the site uses it as a clever way to optimize bandwidth. My question to the API team is that is it safe to rely on it in production environment?

I’d like to use it in a mobile app, so the cross-domain issue is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undocumented features should be treated as volatile, sorry. Though there are no plans to change this format right now, I can't make any promises about it.

Interestingly, the waveform as a PNG file is actually smaller, if bandwidth is your only concern.

Comment: That's it! I knew something similar existed but all I found was wave64.it
Thanks!